# Validating foreign key through tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm trying to validate a foreign key constraint on my table through another table, but I'm not sure how to go about it, or even the correct nomenclature to google.

I have a User table:

```sql
create table User ( id uuid primary key );
```

Each user can have multiple stores:

```sql
create table Store(
   id uuid primary key,
   user_id uuid foreign key store_user_id_fk references User (id)
);
```

and each user+store can have products

```sql
create table Product(
  id uuid primary key,
  user_id uuid foreign key product_user_id_fk references User (id), 
  store_id uuid foreign key product_sotre_id_fk references Store (id),
)
```

My question is: how can I write a constraint on `Product` such that any (`user_id`,`store_id`) combination also must have a valid entry in the `Store` table? The case I'm trying to prevent is an entry being added to `Product` where the store does not also belong to the user.

Is there some way of adding:

```sql
CHECK ( store_id == Store.id and user_id == Store.user_id )
```

To the product table?

Comment: Not necessary. Just drop user_id column from Product. You can always get the user_id through the Store. A particular Product row relates to exactly 1 Store row. Which contains the user_id. This does require a slight change. Make store.user_id and product.store_id not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, I'm pretty sure it would just be:

```
create table Product(
  id uuid primary key,
  user_id uuid foreign key product_user_id_fk references User (id), 
  store_id uuid foreign key product_sotre_id_fk references Store (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id, store_id) REFERENCES store(user_id, id)
);
```

This would indicate that the primary key of store should be (id, user_id) not just id or, at at minimum, it should have a UNIQUE constraint on (id, user_id).